# Rails Routing Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Orders can have many states.  I would like to create named routes for those.  I need the state to be passed in to the controller as a param.  Here is what I was thinking, but it obviously does not work.

```
match "order/:state/:id" => "orders#%{state}", as: "%{state}"
```

So I would like order/address/17 to route to orders#address, with :state and :id being passed in as params.  Likewise, order/shipping/17 would route to orders#shipping, again :state and :id would be passed in.

Here is the controller.

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :load_order, only: [:address, :shipping, :confirmation, :receipt]
  before_filter :validate_state, only: [:address, :shipping, :confirmation, :receipt]


  def address
    @order.build_billing_address unless @order.billing_address
    @order.build_shipping_address unless @order.shipping_address
  end


  def shipping
    @shipping_rates = @order.calculate_shipping_rates
  end


  def confirmation

  end


  def receipt

  end

  private 

  def load_order
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Check to see if the user is on the correct action
  def validate_state
    if params[:state]
      unless params[:state] == @order.state
        redirect_to eval("#{@order.state}_path(:#{@order.state},#{@order.id})")
        return
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Here is what we ended up going with:

**routes.rb**

```
%w(address shipping confirmation receipt).each do |state|
    match "order/#{state}/:id", :to => "orders##{state}", :as => state, :state => state
end
```

**orders_controller.rb**

```
def validate_state
    if params[:state]
      unless params[:state] == @order.state
        redirect_to(eval("#{@order.state}_path(@order)"))
        return
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: If your url is `/order/address/17`, where state information is taken from? If this is not intended url, what is it?

Comment: I just edited it to show a little more of what I am doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to create dynamic named routes with that sort of syntax, but you're basically just using `:state` as the `:action`. If you replace `:state` with `:action` and specify the controller manually, it'll work. Obviously, you will have to change your code to look at `params[:action]` rather than `params[:state]` (or map that variable in a before_filter), but beyond that it should work fine.

```
match "order/:action/:id", :controller => "orders"
```

Be aware that if orders has RESTful resource mappings like `create` or `delete`, this route would allow GET requests to them, which would be bad; you may just want to add explicit routes for each action you want to complete. This will let you get `params[:state]`, as well:

```
%w(address shipping).each do |state|
  match "order/#{state}/:id", :to => "orders##{state}", :as => state, :state => state
end
```

Comment: This is a great response.  Thank you for that second part, made a huge difference in how we implemented it.